# Impact of '??' on cyclomatic complexity in Dart

Tags: dart, cyclomatic-complexity

Should the `??`, `??=`, `?.`, `?...` operators consider as new path in the code when calculating the cyclomatic complexity of a method?

Comment: I also question this myself. It seems that [`dart_code_metrics`](https://github.com/dart-code-checker/dart-code-metrics) consider `?.`, `??` and `??=` as a complexity increasing factor. [source](https://github.com/dart-code-checker/dart-code-metrics/blob/master/lib/src/analyzers/lint_analyzer/metrics/metrics_list/cyclomatic_complexity/cyclomatic_complexity_flow_visitor.dart) I don't know, however, any source regarding this subject...